# How to access file in FormData in multer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, fetch, multer

I am trying to upload file from a react front-end with `fetch` to node.js backend with multer. Below is my `fetch` code:

```
submitpost=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        var data=new FormData();
        data.append('file',this.state.shareImage)
        fetch("http://localhost:8080/post", {
             method: 'POST',
             body: data
        }).then((response) =>  {
           console.log(response.json());
        })
    }
```

The image is in the state of the component. Below is the server code:

```
const express=require('express')
const app=express()
const bodyParser=require('body-parser')
const multer=require('multer')
const cors=require('cors')

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(cors());

var storage1 = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {

        // Uploads is the Upload_folder_name
        cb(null, "images")
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + "-" + Date.now()+".jpg")
    }
})

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage1
})
app.post('/post',upload.single('myfile'),(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send(JSON.stringify({'status':'success'}))
})


app.listen(8080,function(error) {
    if(error) throw error
        console.log("Server created Successfully on PORT 8080")
})
```

When I see in the console, `req.body` is empty.
This is how my `input` looks like:

```
<input type="file" 
                                accept="image/*" 
                                name="myfile"
                                id="file"
                                style={{display: 'none'}}
                                onChange={(event)=>{this.handleChange(event)}} 
                                />
```

Below is the Request Headers as seen in network tab:

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 135326
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryE9U4gJpcqK2hAdXC
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
```

My question is if this is the correct way to receive files. If yes, why `req.body` is empty?

Please help me to find the problem.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

The code currently initializes the `multer` middleware, but does not use it. According to the [documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#usage), here's how you'd use it:

```
app.post("/post", upload.single("file"), (req, res) => {
  // "file" is the name of the field which contains the file

  // req.file is the `avatar` file
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
  console.log(req.file);
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send(JSON.stringify({ status: "success" }));
});
```

As an additional side-note, express has a helper for working with JSON. You can replace `res.send(JSON.stringify(...))` with `res.json(...)`:

```
app.post("/post", upload.single("file"), (req, res) => {
  // "file" is the name of the field which contains the file

  // req.file is the `avatar` file
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
  console.log(req.file);
  console.log(req.body);
  res.json({ status: "success" });
});
```

Comment: When I did this change, I get an error on server console: ``MulterError:Unexpected field``

Comment: Is there any problem on the fron-end??

Comment: The `"file"` in `upload.single("file")` refers to the field in the `FormData`. The field's name should be the same in both - which in your supplied code is correct (`data.append('file', ...)`. If you `console.log(this.state.shareImage)`, is it a `File` instance?

Comment: I've made sure that the name attribute is same as single attribute. Also, ``this.state.shareImage`` is a File Instance. ``File {name: "Screenshot from 2021-05-22 14-29-56.png", lastModified: 1621673996897, lastModifiedDate: Sat May 22 2021 14:29:56 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 135114, …}`` Still, i'm getting same error.

Comment: Could you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67649271/edit) to show the current up-to-date code?

Comment: And could you please take a look at the POST request made by the client in your browser's developer tools' network tab to see just what the name of the fields are? Here's how to do that in [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/).

Comment: There is only one field: ``file  (binary)``. Also, I have updated my code.

Comment: `upload.single('myfile')` should be `upload.single('file')` - since you have `data.append('file', ...)`

Comment: Thanks. It is working now! You can update your answer now.